# datetime picker asp.net within formview

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime

I want to add time picker in the ajax asp:CalendarExtender.
I want to bind the pick in a db column with datetime type
my asp code is :

```
<asp:FormView ID="FormView1" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" OnPreRender="myFormView_PreRender" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#336666" BorderStyle="Double" BorderWidth="3px" CellPadding="4" DataKeyNames="ID" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" GridLines="Horizontal">
    <EditItemTemplate>

        DATE_TIME:

         <asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxDatetime" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("DATE_TIME") %>' ></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarExtender1" runat="server" TargetControlID="TextBoxDatetime" ></asp:CalendarExtender>
```

c# code:

```
protected void myFormView_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (FormView1.CurrentMode == FormViewMode.Edit)
    {
        TextBox txtdate = FormView1.FindControl("TextBoxDatetime") as TextBox;
        DropDownList txthour = FormView1.FindControl("hourddl") as DropDownList;
        DropDownList txtminutes = FormView1.FindControl("MinutesDdl") as DropDownList;
        DropDownList txtpmam = FormView1.FindControl("AMPMddl") as DropDownList;
        string time = string.Format("{0}-{1}{2}", txthour.Text, txtminutes.Text, txtpmam.Text);

        testLabel.Text = time;
    }
}
```

Something like this???any idea for smth free? I Think if is it possible with two litle dropdownlists that gives the hours and the minutes.But how it can be with the calendar extender.

Comment: Just convert the date whcih is collected into the textbox to datetime.

Comment: Have you tried to use `SelectedDate` of CalendarExtender control and bind to that?

Comment: Yes I have done that and it works, but it is only for date.I want to have also timepicker.Maybe to combine with 3 dropdownlist...?